# golang test error "cannot use as error value in assignment: *"gorm.io/gorm".DB does not implement error"

Tags: go

I am trying to test user registration with echo but I get an error.
Here is the specific error.
cannot use r.Create(id, name, password, email) (value of type *"gorm.io/gorm".DB) as error value in assignment: *"gorm.io/gorm".DB does not implement error
How can I resolve this error to make a correct test?

```
package test

import (
    "regexp"
    "testing"

    sqlmock "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
    "github.com/...../model"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

func getDBMock() (*gorm.DB, sqlmock.Sqlmock, error) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    gdb, err := gorm.Open("postgres", db)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    return gdb, mock, nil
}
func TestCreate(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, err := getDBMock()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    db.LogMode(true)
    r := model.Repository{DB: db}

    id := "2222"
    name := "BBBB"
    password := "mfsdmSD34"
    email := "dmvsdmvo@.com"


    // Mock設定
    mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(
        `INSERT INTO "users" ("id","name","passowrd","email") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)
         RETURNING "users"."id"`)).WithArgs(id, name,password,email).
        WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id"}).AddRow(id))

    // 実行
    err = r.Create(id, name,password,email)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

```
package model

type User struct {
    ID       int    `json:"id" gorm:"praimaly_key"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Email    string `json:"email"`
}

func CreateUser(user *User) {
    db.Create(user)
}

func FindUser(u *User) User {
    var user User
    db.Where(u).First(&user)
    return user
}
```

```
package model

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err Error
    dsn := "user:pass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    db, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
      panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Todo{})
}
```

Comment: The `(model.Repository).Create(id, name, password, email)` method returns a value of type `*gorm.io/gorm.DB`, but in the `TestCreate` function you are trying to assign the result to the variable `err` which is of type `error`.  `*gorm.DB` does not implement the `error` interface and that is why you are getting the error. So you either need to change the return type of the `(model.Repository).Create` method, or you need to change the variable type to which you assign the returned `*gorm.DB` result.

Comment: How do I change the test code as I am new to using go?

Comment: [`gorm.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB) has an `Error` field of type `error` which is used by `gorm.DB` to store error values. So if the repo `Create` method returns `gorm.DB` and you want to check the error, you can "chain" the `Error` field access to the `Create` call, e.g. `err = r.Create(id,name,password,email).Error` <- notice the trailing `.Error`, that's basically "immediately" accessing the `Error` field of the returned `gorm.DB` instance.

Comment: I got the error " gorm redeclared in this block".

Comment: The *"... redeclared in this block"* error occurs when you redeclare the same *variable* in a single block. Sos that means that somewhere in your code, there is a *block* of code where you a declaring the same variable more than once. https://go.dev/play/p/49tl8RbrBQw